# Fetch text from input box after page reload

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fetch value generated after clicking submit button from an input box. But the page reloads so it doesn't return anything. From website http://www.wasitviewed.com/

I have tried .text option using the xpath of the input box.

```
WebDriverWait(drivername, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="content"]/iframe""")))

result = drivername.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="results"]/p[1]/input""").text
print result
```

I would expect it to print the link generated.

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception for your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to get the text value from an `input` element, use `get_attribute("value")` instead of `.text`.

Use this to get the result.

```py
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='results']/p[1]/input""").get_attribute("value")

print(result)
```